# Can you implement polls?

Tags: feature-request

It would be great to create polls on Stack Exchange. For example:

> What is your favorite programming language?
>
> 1. C
> 2. C++
> 3. Java
> 4. PHP
> 5. ...

I think many people would use this.

Comment: That doesn't really make great polls. What does favorite really mean? What do you learn about the why a language is a favorite? How to correct for biases due to non-representative composition of the poll voters? What would be the error of the poll results? Should there be reputation for posting such a question? Is this really the right place for it? How long should they run before they get outdated?

Comment: Well you could see what the most popular programming language is.

Comment: *Favorite programming language* for what purpose? Polls don't add much actionable value here.

Comment: The only poll we have is SO's developer survey.  Beyond that, the site doesn't lend itself well to polls, and the majority of users would like to keep it that way.

Comment: We used to have polls, but the old webpages no longer function: https://stats.stackexchange.com/polls/2/what-should-our-domain-name-be https://unix.stackexchange.com/polls/2/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-merge

Answer (score 10):

The company conducts a yearly developer survey which asks questions like this. In my opinion, having too many polls would be counter-productive and annoying to users.

The developer survey includes that information and so much more, so it is useful to anybody looking to get a perspective of the current dev world.

[Here's the results from the most recent developer survey.](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019)

Answer (score 5):

Questions leading to opinion based answers are actively discouraged across this site, so this proposal is in contradiction to that.

Also, how would this be useful in the context of building a set of Q & A sites? The fact that I prefer C++ to anything else on your list is not much use to anyone else when faced with a particular problem.

The current site format would have to be reworked too - the answers section wouldn't really be relevant, and choices not easily voted on.

Why not build this yourself if you believe it's useful?

Comment: Well I'm not the owner of stackexchange. So how could I do it...

Comment: @somega He/she means build a separate application, and honestly, polls would be counter-productive (read my answer for more info).